# Pandas TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the code:

```
if df1.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank'] > df2.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank']:
    df1 = df1[(df1['Type' == 'A'])]
    df2 = df2[(df2['Type' == 'D'])]
else:
    df1 = df1[(df1['Type' == 'D'])]
    df2 = df2[(df2['Type' == 'A'])]
```

But it is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'
```

So how can i fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to do on 'Rank' column ? count, mean, sum ? Use aggregation function on Rank column
Try this:

df1.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank'].sum() > df2.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank'].sum()

Comment: Rank column is a classement of value so i don't have idea for this, like just compare rank of two. I have tried sum() but it doesn't work and inform 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()'

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide some aggregate method for groupby such as

```
df1.groupby(["id", "Date"]).sum()['Rank']
```

or

```
df1.groupby(["id", "Date"]).max()['Rank']
```

this will result in a dataframe instead of the SeriesGroupBy object that is returned by groupby()

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried this method before but it doesn't work and inform 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()'

Comment: That error is coming from trying to compare two series with `>`  this cant give a single Boolean value that the if statement requires, what do you expect df1.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank'] to return?

Comment: it has two type 'D' and 'A' for all value, if in the case of rank df1 > rank df2 in the same id and date, so keep df1 type D and df2 type A. and inverse.

Comment: Ok when you say rank df1 do you expect this to be some value for the whole data frame? or is it a rank within the data frame perhaps?

Comment: Hi, I created a new question to better describe the value of rank. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69836504/17037971