# Python TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two datafames df1 and df2.

Compare in same day and id

- if rank df1 < rank df2 so keep value df1 type 'D' and df2 type 'A'.
- if rank df1 > rank df2 so keep value df1 type 'A' and df2 type 'D'.

df1:

| id | day | rank | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25/01 | 22 | D |
| 1 | 25/01 | 22 | A |
| 5 | 25/01 | 66 | D |
| 5 | 25/01 | 66 | A |
| 10 | 26/01 | 55 | D |

df2:

| id | day | rank | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25/01 | 58 | D |
| 1 | 25/01 | 58 | A |
| 5 | 25/01 | 10 | D |
| 5 | 25/01 | 10 | A |
| 10 | 26/01 | 100 | D |
| 10 | 26/01 | 100 | A |

Output df1:

| id | day | rank | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25/01 | 22 | D |
| 5 | 25/01 | 66 | A |
| 10 | 26/01 | 55 | D |

Output df2:

| id | day | rank | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25/01 | 58 | A |
| 5 | 25/01 | 10 | D |
| 10 | 26/01 | 100 | A |

I have the code:

```
if df1.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank'] > df2.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank']:
    df1 = df1[(df1['Type' == 'A'])]
    df2 = df2[(df2['Type' == 'D'])]
else:
    df1 = df1[(df1['Type' == 'D'])]
    df2 = df2[(df2['Type' == 'A'])]
```

But it is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'
```

So how can i fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are sizes of the two dataframes (df1, df2) always same?

Comment: No, it's difference

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank']
```

Is of instance "SeriesGroupBy".

From the [Pandas-groupby](https://realpython.com/pandas-groupby/) documents, You want to put str after to get the value.
And then you can convert it to an int to be compared.

```
int(df1.groupby(["id", "Date"])['Rank'].str)
```

Comment: But Serie groupby can't use str because it doesn't have attribute 'str'

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': [1, 1, 5, 5],
        'day': ['25/01', '25/01', '25/01', '25/01'],
        'rank': [22, 22, 66, 66],
        'type': ['D', 'A', 'D', 'A'],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': [1, 1, 5, 5],
        'day': ['25/01', '25/01', '25/01', '25/01'],
        'rank': [58, 58, 10, 10],
        'type': ['D', 'A', 'D', 'A'],
    }
)

df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(['id', 'day', 'rank'])
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['id', 'day', 'rank'])

for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    if df1.iloc[i]['rank'] > df2.iloc[i]['rank']:
        df1.iloc[i, 3] = 'A'
        df2.iloc[i, 3] = 'D'
    else:
        df1.iloc[i, 3] = 'D'
        df2.iloc[i, 3] = 'A'

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

This will print what you want:

```
   id    day  rank type
0   1  25/01    22    D
2   5  25/01    66    A

   id    day  rank type
0   1  25/01    58    A
2   5  25/01    10    D
```

Comment: That sounds great. > doesn't work between Series or SeriesGroupBy so I solved this issus in a loop :)